# How to copy values from one SQL Server table to equally named columns in another using LINQ

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Sometimes in SQL Server we have a temporary import table ('Import') with lots of columns and another table ('Production') also with a lot of columns, and **many columns have the same names** (but not all), and **we simply need to write the values of the equally named columns from one to the other** (without processing them). Same database, equally named columns in both tables have the same types.

Usually we do it like this:

```
// Lots and lots of columns copied without processing
Production.ColumnA = Import.ColumnA; 
Production.ColumnB = Import.ColumnB;
Production.ColumnC = Import.ColumnC;
// [...]

// Some with processing
Production.ColumnQ1 = DoSomething(Import.ColumnQ2);
```

That's annoying and somehow redundant if there are many columns. What would be the best way to copy those equally named columns automatically, like in this **pseudo-code**:

```
foreach(var importRow in ImportRows)
    foreach(Column col in Production.Columns)
        if(Import.Columns.Contains(col.Name)) newProductionRow[col] = importRow[col];
```

(Very similar to what one could do using DataTables with indices, but we don't want that here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using reflection to copy from one object to another, like described in this blog:  http://goneale.com/2009/02/16/cloning-object-properties-via-reflection/

If you have lot's of different types of tables you need to copy, you could add generics to the mix, so you only need to create one "copy" function.

Comment: +1 for the perfect answer and the great link to boot.  Property cloning is the best way to handle this sort of problem